# Add background image to quarto website home page

Tags: html, css, quarto

In a quarto website, how do I add a background image filling the entire page but only to the home page?

I have a working solution which adds the background correctly, but does it across the entire website. In the example below, I do not want the report page to have the background image. It should have a plain white background, navbar and footer.

Reproducible example. Creating the following files:

**_quarto.yml**

```
project:
  type: website

website:
  title: "Sunset Sea"
  navbar:
    background: transparent
    left:
      - text: Home
        href: "index.html"
      - text: Report
        href: "report.html"
  page-footer:
    border: false
    background: transparent
    foreground: DimGray
    left: Left content
    right: Right content

format:
  html:
    theme: "styles.css"
```

**index.qmd**

```
---
format: html
---

# Sunset Sea

Welcome to Sunset Sea.
```

**report.qmd**

```
---
title: "Report"
format: html
---

## Heading 1

This is a report
```

**styles.css**

```
/*-- scss:defaults --*/

body {
  background-image: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/189349/pexels-photo-189349.jpeg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  /*background-position: center center;*/
  /*background-attachment: fixed;*/
}
```

Run `quarto preview`

[image]

Possibly a solution is to add a div just before or after the body div with a specific class only on the home page and target that class with css. I am not quite sure how to go about doing that.

I have tried [`include-before-body`](https://quarto.org/docs/output-formats/html-basics.html#includes) but that does not cover navbar and footer anyway.

Updated part of **_quarto.yml**

```
format:
  html:
    theme: "styles.css"
    include-before-body: before.html
    include-after: after.html
```

**before.html**

```
<div class="splash">
```

**after.html**

```
</div>
```

Update **styles.css***

```
.splash {
  background-image: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/189349/pexels-photo-189349.jpeg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

[image]

`Quarto 1.2.1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**index.qmd** and **Report.qmd** will generate two different webpages. So if you want to add any style specific to **index.html** define the css styles (within `style` tag) in the **index.qmd** directly, instead of **style.css**.

**index.qmd**

```
---
format: html
---

<style>
  body {
  background-image: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/189349/pexels-photo-189349.jpeg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
  
</style>


# Sunset Sea

Welcome to Sunset Sea.
```

**style.css**

(do not specify the background images in the style.css)

```
/*-- scss:defaults --*/
```

---

[image: home page with background image]

---

[image: Report page with no background image]

---